# Spring MVC TrailingSlash matching

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am using Spring MVC 4.1, and this is the core config:

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {""})
public class MvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }
    public void configurePathMatch(PathMatchConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.setUseSuffixPatternMatch(true);
        configurer.setUseTrailingSlashMatch(false);
    }
    ....
}

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/api/deps")
public class DepartmentCtrl {
    @RequestMapping(value = "", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public Result index() {
        return ...;
    }
}
```

While when I open this the url:

```
/context/api/deps
```

I will get the result as expected, however once I will get a 404 once I visit the link:

```
/context/api/deps/
```

As shown, I have config the `PathMatchConfigurer`  by `setUseTrailingSlashMatch(false)` , but it seems that it does not work.

Is there anything wrong in my configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens when you pass "/" in the value attribute of RequestMapping Annotation?

Answer (score 4):

use this:

```
setUseTrailingSlashMatch(true)
```

According to [javadoc](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/method/annotation/RequestMappingHandlerMapping.html#setUseTrailingSlashMatch-boolean-), `setUseTrailingSlashMatch` determines:

> Whether to match to URLs irrespective of the presence of a trailing
>   slash. If enabled a method mapped to "/users" also matches to
>   "/users/".

Honestly, there is no need for this piece of configuration, since its enabled by default and you by passing `false` to it, disabled it.

Comment: As i said, its the default behavior.

Comment: It's no longer the default to be set to true. Since Spring-Framework 6 it is set to false.